# detect current active subview of a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a navigation controller. i want to runa background thread on that controller which checks which subview is loaded currently in the navigation controller. loaded means tha active viewable subview.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to (or should) use a background thread for this. Simply set the navigation controller's delegate and implement the method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can then store the currently active view controller in an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

there is a `UINavigationController` property for that (from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController)):

> topViewController
>
> The view controller at the top of the navigation stack. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIViewController *topViewController

simply do:

```
UIViewController* topController = navigationController.topViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.view.subviews) 
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for (UINavigationController *view in self.view.subviews) 
{
}